# Why wifiManager.setTimeout(60) is not working?

Tags: esp8266

in this code I am using wifiManager.setTimeout(60); so that when it fails to connect to the wifi it should restart. However, wifiManager.setTimeout(60) is not working at all. It get stuck and display these lines :

*WM: AutoConnect

*WM: Connecting as wifi client...

*WM: Using last saved values, should be faster

It never displays this :

"failed to connect and hit timeout"

which means wifiManager.setTimeout(60) is not working . Below is the code:

```
  #include <ESP8266WiFi.h>          

 //needed for library 
 #include <DNSServer.h>
 #include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
 #include <WiFiManager.h>          



  void setup() {
       // put your setup code here, to run once:
       Serial.begin(115200);

      //WiFiManager
       //Local intialization. Once its business is done, there is no need to 
       //keep it around
        WiFiManager wifiManager;
      //reset settings - for testing
      //wifiManager.resetSettings();

     //sets timeout until configuration portal gets turned off
     //useful to make it all retry or go to sleep
      //in seconds

      wifiManager.setTimeout(60);


  //fetches ssid and pass and tries to connect
  //if it does not connect it starts an access point with the specified name
 //here  "AutoConnectAP"
 //and goes into a blocking loop awaiting configuration

  if(!wifiManager.autoConnect("AutoConnectAP")) {
     Serial.println("failed to connect and hit timeout");
     delay(3000);
     //reset and try again, or maybe put it to deep sleep
     //ESP.reset();
     ESP.restart();
     //ESP.deepSleep(20e6, WAKE_RFCAL);
    delay(5000);
   } 

   //if you get here you have connected to the WiFi
   Serial.println("connected...yeey :)");

    ESP.deepSleep(20e6, WAKE_RFCAL);
    delay(3000);

 }

  void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

  }
```

I am using ESP8266 thing dev board. Can anyone please tell me what is wrong and how to resolve the issue ? Thank You!!

Comment: Are you certain this comment is on one line? `//Local intialization. Once its business is done, there is no need to keep it around`. Also are you sure what times are in seconds and what is in mS?

Comment: Yes I have corrected it. Time is in seconds. 60 mean 1 minute.

Comment: You'll probably need to pursue this with the author of the library.

Comment: it must be using the last wifi settings - because `Using last saved values` means that it has successfully connected to an AP - though, it's surprising that `"connected...yeey :)"` isn't output

Comment: add delay(500) after Serial.begin to see all the output from the beginning

Answer (score -1):

Try using setConfigPortalTimeout(60) instead of setTimeout(60)

Because it has been updated in version 0.10 of WiFiManager library.
see : https://github.com/tzapu/WiFiManager#010

Comment: `setTimeout` just calls `setConfigPortalTimeout` - so there's no difference